# What is the opposite of frontal?

Tags: antonyms

What is a term which refers to the areas in the back or rear, with the same scope as the word "frontal"?  The satirical/humorous term *backal* exists, but is not really a word (or appropriate to use in writing).

Comment: Could you give some more context? If it was related to e.g. a car, I wouldn't use "dorsal" or "posterior". Maybe "rear (end)" but you used that term yourself in the question

Comment: @Stefan: Would you use “frontal” for a car? I believe that the question’s title and its first sentence define its scope.

Comment: I guess suitvertices did like the dorsal - and that is correct for biological/anatomical use. I was thinking of the use: adjective: of, in, or at the front: a frontal view; frontal attack. The car example was probably not so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term that is used most often is [***dorsal***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dorsal). When used of a human being, or an upright animal, it refers to the back, or to that which pertains to the back. When used of a quadruped, it refers to the upper side, which usually corresponds to the back of an upright animal. While [***frontal***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frontal) is used of a human being or an upright animal, the corresponding term for quadrupeds is [***ventral***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ventral).  ***Dorsal*** and ***ventral*** are also used of inanimate objects that are oriented horizontally, such as submarines.

Comment: "ventral" is also used for humans, since as that link mentions, anatomically "frontal" refers to the forehead region (like the "frontal lobe" of the brain), or to a section that divides the body into front and back sections, rather than to the front side of the body as a whole. But perhaps more common than "dorsal" and "ventral" are "posterior" and "anterior"